# How to store documents content in Solr 6.4?

Tags: solr, highlighting

I'm trying to index documents using Windows version of post, using command like bellow:

```
java -Dc=docs -Dauto=yes -Dc=docs -Ddata=files -Drecursive=yes -jar
post.jar C:\docs
```

I can see that documents are indexed correctly but I want to store extracted text to use highlighting. I added to my managed-schema fields like:

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="source" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="content" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="content" type="strings"/>
```

but it doesn't work and I cannot return in my search content of documents. How can I store text extracted from doc, docx, pdf files and return it in my query?

Comment: didn't get what u looking for. you have problem with highlighting query term in results. ?

Comment: As far as I understand, I need to store extracted text to use highlighting. So, my problem is that I don't how to retrieve content of the documents and make Solr to store it. Sorry, if something is not clear, but I'm new in Solr and I don't exacty know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **bin/post** (not sure about post.jar, but I believe so as well) will tell you what type it determined each file to be and to what handler it is submitted.

For example, MSWord, PDF and so on are all going to the **/extract** handler, which uses Tika to extract the content.

Then, if you look in the **solrconfig.xml** for the definition of the **/extract** handler, you will see  the parameters that tell you how to map the extracted content, which includes the names of the fields. Then, you can make those fields stored and reindex.

Answer (score 0):

post.jar will performing indexing operation. so when you index any document (there is an option which can be set to true/false to store content in schema.xml file) you can search for its content.

you can use highlight only if you store it.

check this [Link](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html) to understand how indexing, searching is done

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that I have to set _stored_ option to _true_ but I'm not sure in which field. I tried to store fields like _text_, `_text_`, _source_, _content_ - but there is no text from documents, however there are indexed correctly. Do you know which field contain all content from processed document?

Comment: Check for `content` field. set bot indexed and stored = true for content.  you will understand it better. restart solr, reindex document and search(dont forget this step restart and reindex). upvote or accept my answer if you find useful. cheers.